# Reading String data from a file stored on phone storage

Tags: java, android, file, storage

How can I read String from a file stored on my phone and then then store that string to a variable. For example a file **file.txt** in my downloads folder contains some text and I want to store it into a variable.

I've tried some code available online but it's not working maybe I'm missing something!

Comment: Please post that code

Comment: You have the [Informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed?userid=22675684) badge. Did you not read [ask] ? Can you expand on _it's not working_ ? Are you getting an error? If so then [edit] your question and post the error text. Or is the variable's value not what you expect? Then post the value you are getting as well as the value you expect to get.